# Leaflet plugin with geoJson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-visualization

I have a web component which uses leaflet and Leaflet google plugin from https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-google and I cannot seem to add markers to the map.

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               150.10031104000007,
               -36.009585815999969
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "title":"3910 Princes Highway Coila",
            "link":"",
            "category":"Advice",
            "guid":"",
            "guid_isPermaLink":"true",
            "pubDate":"11/05/2020 4:46:00 AM",
            "description":"Blah "
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and my code is as below

```
      var map = L.map(mapDiv).setView([-33.450301, 150.060243], 6);
      var zoomControl = new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' });

      var baseballIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
        iconSize: [32, 37],
        iconAnchor: [16, 37],
        popupAnchor: [0, -28]
      });

      var layersControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, { collapsed: false });
      layersControl.addTo(map);
      zoomControl.addTo(map);

      map.addLayer(ggl);

      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.title) {
            console.log(feature.properties.title);
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
        }
    }
        $.getJSON(the geojson data, function(data) {
          L.geoJson(data, {
          return L.marker(latlng, {icon: baseballIcon});
           onEachFeature: onEachFeature  
          }).addTo(map);
        });        
      }
```

I cannot see a marker on the map although I can see that the data in console.log(feature.properties.title) but no markers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Check your syntax around `return L.marker(...)`

Comment: return new L.marker(latlng, {icon: baseballIcon}); did not work. What I missing.

Comment: You're missing a [syntactically correct object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) when passing options as the second parameter of the `L.geoJson()` factory method.